# OneLogin + SAML + SCIM

Tags: saml, wif, onelogin

I'm integrating a service with OneLogin. In particular, need to implement SAML-P login AND SCIM v2 endpoint in a multi-tiered .NET application, which is using Windows Identity Foundation behind the scenes.

Both SCIM v2 and SAML-P work fine independently, however I'm having issues combining these two in the same SP record OneLogin-side, because of signing options:

- It is possible to get OneLogin to sign just SAML assertion in a SAML response. This is what WIF wants to see, and this is what "SAML Test Connector (IdP)" template of OneLogin does.
- "SCIM Provisioner with SAML (SCIM v2)" template however signs the whole SAML response, and not just the assertion, and WIF does not like that, complaining about unsigned SAML assertion.

Neither template has a visible option to configure what is signed, that would be similar to what Azure AD SAML configuration has (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9kFf.png ).

Is there a way to change SCIM template to sign just the assertion (or response + assertion), similar to what "SAML Test Connector (IdP)" does?

Comment: For more advanced SAML connector settings I'd just reach out to OneLogin support directly. OneLogin has just announced a new 'Advanced' SAML connector in their catalog that supports end-user control over things like signing format, etc. So contact support and maybe they can combine these two bits of functionality.